# connecting JDBC

Tags: oracle, servlets

Hi guys:)
I am new to servlet.I dont know how to connect oracle database to the servlet application. Can anyone paste Oracle JDBC coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register Database Connection parameters: 
 To include your application specific connection parameters of your database, edit the file data-sources.xml under \config directory. Add the following lines to create a data source. Change the hostname, port, username/password, database name, driver type to suit  your application. Make changes for url after @ symbol. Save the file. This will register the data-source which can be used across your application.

```
<data-source 
  class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource" 
  name="ifso817DS" 
  location="jdbc/Loneifso817DS" 
  xa-location="jdbc/xa/ifso817XADS" 
  ejb-location="jdbc/Pooledifso817DS" 
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@insn104a.idc.oracle.com:1521:ifso817" 
  connection-driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
  username="travel" 
  password="travel" 
  inactivity-timeout="30" 
/>
```

That is taken from: http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/servlets/samples/TravelServlet/Readme.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of articles discussing this, but I'll give you the basic steps:

1. download Oracle JDBC driver from [Oracle's homepage](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html), it's called `ojdbc6.jar` if you're using Java 6
2. make sure your application can find it on its classpath
3. since you are using servlets, you're also using a Java application server; read relevant documentation about setting up a JNDI binding to your database (usually this binding will be called `jdbc/connectionName`)
4. inside of your application, use this code:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/connectionName");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

This should be enough to get you started.

For more information, Google is your friend. Check out [Wikipedia's JDBC page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). Google "Oracle JDBC connection" for more info.

One thing that might give you headaches if you've never done stuff like this: when defining Oracle's URL for your app. server, it's format is as follows:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:[user/password]@[host][:port]:SID
```

So you have to substitute appropriate values when defining the connection for a JNDI binding.

Comment: Hey thanks, now i understood, its pretty simple to access JDBC in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/JDBCandServlet.htm. You need to modify driver class name and connection url to connect to Oracle DB. Check http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/OracleJDBCDriverload.htm for Oracle DB connection details

Comment: Thank you Amit,i referred java2s.